# Neo4j unique user node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am making a user registration page. In this page users can enter username, name, email address and their password

I wanted to first check if the username was already taken, for this I used the following

```
MERGE (n:user { username: "newuser" })
ON CREATE SET n += { other properties }
RETURN n
```

This seems to work well. However, I actually want to check if for two fields username and email address. Basically allow new user if username and email address aren't taken.

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE (n:user { username: "newuser", email: "email" })
```

Will check for both fields and create/merge accordingly

If you want to check availability first, you should do another query for that.

To do the check

```
 MATCH (n:user) 
 WHERE n.username = {newuser} OR n.email = {email}
 RETURN count(n)
```

If it returns > 0, you're matched.

Comment: this is working as an `AND` operator, I need something that works like an `OR`. I need to check if the username or the email is already taken... how do we do that?